# Can you run a function in an input value in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to do run a function and pass some parameters in my input value, but it's giving me this error:
`Invalid value for prop`value`on <input> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.`

I remember reading somewhere once that you can use functions in `value`, but this isn't working for me. Is there another way.

```js
value={() => this.handleMapping(row.servername,  "Data Source Server")}
```

Error: `Invalid value for prop`value`on <input> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.`

Comment: can you precise what is the form tag in which you inject value?

Comment: Hi Annah, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: You can use a change handler (`onChange`) and inside it run `this.setState({ value: this.handleMapping(...) })` and in your component just pass it in as `value={this.state.value}` so it is up-to-date on every change of the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have provided an anonymous function here,

```
value={() => this.handleMapping(row.servername,  "Data Source Server")}
```

Instead you need to just provide the function, which will execute when the component loads.

```
value={this.handleMapping(row.servername,  "Data Source Server")}
```

Also make sure your `handleMapping` function should return something which can be treated as input value.

[Simplified Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h4bfhr)

**Note:** Also make sure to provide `onChange` handler on input.

Comment: Do you know where it's documented that you use this syntax?   I ask because I thought (years ago) that the anonymous function was the recommended way to do this.  See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html, that uses this syntax `<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>`

Comment: @PatS The syntax you are sharing is applicable when we have a click event. The OP wants to load the values automatically on the very first load on the page. The syntax I am sharing is to call the function automatically on the load of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute/run function as you need some event to execute it, however you can use function in value only if return some integer or string.

Comment: Explain clearly or share the complete code, So that we can suggest you better way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value={ (() => this.handleMapping(row.servername,  "Data Source Server")) () }
```

This will run your anonymous function